# Eclipse - Target “unknown” in Android device chooser doesn't show sony zr(c5502)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, device, target

I had the same problem with my phone sony  zr(c5502), when connected to a Win 7 64 machine, not showing up as an available device in Eclipse
Turn on MTP, which is disabled by default by going to Settings > Storage > Menu (Upper right hand corner) > USB computer connection > Media Device (MTP)

i install  driver show driver in device manager by sonysa0107 name in pc
sony zr mobie

Comment: How to run a program on your phone sony zr    ،Personal computer with the Eclipse runtime , but knows it 's shown as offline while the phone is placed in debug mode

Comment: Eclipse - Target “unknown” in Android device chooserr

Answer (score 1):

Just reconnect your device and turn on (Allow USB Debugging).
Go to Developer Options -> Check USB Debugging
Check this link: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/

Comment: Thank you for your response method was tested in  sony zr( c5502) state was not able to identify the model

Answer (score 1):

Just refresh the USB connection. while connecting change connection type MTP then Android device chooser will recognize device as on online stage.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can reset your adb connection by menu->windows->show view->others-> android-> devices-> view menu(at the right top corner rotated triangle image) click here, you will find reset adb option over here ,click on it hope it will work.
2. you can disconnect the cord and connect again after disable/enable usb debugging
3. Make sure your system has supported device drivers installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

It first setup sony driver 
And then restart your computer
And so on... 
And then connect your mobil to computer 
Open eclips 
And you will see is not unknown